# Is there a way to show the content of a field taken from the user profile in the comment.tpl.php file?

Tags: entities, users, comments

How does one display a custom field from a user's profile in comment.tpl.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment.tpl.php template file receive a `$comment` value, which contains the comment object. Between its properties, there is `$comment->uid`, which can be used to get the user object for the author of the comment, with `user_load($comment->uid)`. If you are instead interested in the author of the node containing the comment, then you can use the following code.

```
$node = node_load($comment->nid);
$uid = $node->uid;
if ($uid) {
  $user = user_load($uid);
}
```

In both the cases, the code should be used in the preprocess function, not in the template file used for the comments. In this case, `$variables['comment']->uid`, and `$variables['comment']->nid` are instead used.

Comment: Thank you! I have just one question. How do i show term refference field? Thank you!

Comment: That is a different question. `:)` There is probably a question about that already.